# How can I pass a prop from parent component to grandchildren component in react s while skipping the child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to pass a function as prop from a parent component but the function is not needed in the child component, only in the grandchild component.
So I'm trying to find out if there is a way that I can get it done

I've tried my best to research on how to get rhis done but I'm unable to find an explanatory article on this. I will appreciate if anyone can direct me to any useful material online

Comment: Look into context

Comment: You can use central storage like redux, context api

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

For this point you have 3 different ways:

1. Pass prop to child and then to grandchild
2. Create store using State Manager like redux (https://redux-toolkit.js.org/) and have function for whole app.
3. Create context using useContext (https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext)